# toJSON and Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the following BB code.

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'users/',
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }
  });

var user = new UserModel();

user.fetch({
    success: function (user) {
       alert(user.toJSON);
   }
});
```

My php contains:

```
 echo '{"name":"nyname","email":"myemail"}';
```

The alert shows

```
 function(t){return h.clone{(this.attributes)}
```

I am a real newbie with BB.  How do I extract the name and email from this?

Comment: `toJSON` is a method. Call it. But I assume you don't even have to do anything with the method if you just want to access the "properties" of the object. Why don't you read some documentation about models? http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/

Comment: Yes, just figured that user.get('name') is equivalent to user.toJSON.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alerts shows a function because you alert a function refernece. You don't call the function. Try this:

```
alert( user.toJSON() ); // Added brackets ( )
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can't believe I missed that.